# Is it possible to play against a trained bot from the keyboard using gym (Pong)?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, pong, q-learning

I've been working on training a bot(DQN) on Pong using `openai-gym` and `torch`. After some success on the `PongNoFrameskip-v4` environment, it occurred to me that it would be super nice if I would be able to play against this bot after training(and hopefully lose). Recently, I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/examples/agents/keyboard_agent.py) keyboard agent, which seems to allow imitation training - training the bot from your plays. However, I haven't yet found a way to start an environment with my trained model as the right player(green) and play as the other player(brown).

Would really appreciate any advice regarding this topic. Thanks!

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1134) (and links therein) might be informative.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! From what I could see, the ````human_recorder.py```` would allow me to overwrite the controls of the left paddle while the right paddle would be controlled by the trained bot?

Comment: Presumably yes, but I don't have any experience using it.

Comment: Ok, I will try to adapt the script and make updates on progress

Comment: Found this [issue](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1696) as well, hopefully there's more information here.